# How to delete all exe in a pendrive in linux

Tags: command, rm

There are a lot of exe files in my pen-drive (reside in different directories).

How can I delete all the files using Linux command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removes all `exe` files in the current directory tree.

```
find . -name "*.exe" -delete
```

If your pen drive has more than 2 directory , then you need to run this command in each directory.

Comment: To be more specific: the "." means the current directory, so make sure you are in the the directory for the pendrive.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I have a question. I need to delete .exe but only on current folder, not subfolders. is there a way?